# How do I expand my computer's memory so that I can match my 2 samples using matchit?

Tags: r, memory-management, bigdata, propensity-score-matching

I try to match my two samples (Propensity score matching) using the "NNM" method but it does not give me a satisfactory balance. I tried optimal matching but soon ran into memory problems. I tried `memory.size ()` which did not change anything. Apparently `gc()` doesn't help since R does it internally. I'm trying to look at `bigmemory` or `ff` packages, but despite the documentation I can't figure out how to use them and implement the matching using matchit.

```
match.obj <- matchit(ps.formula, data =pts_raw_ps,
                     distance = "glm",
                     method = "optimal",
                     ratio = 1)
```

Below the error message I get when I run my code:

```
Warning: Fewer control units than treated units; not all treated units will get a match.
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 216.1 Gb
```

That is the number of variables in my dataset

```
baseline_vars<-c("sexe","age","age_cat",
                 "BMI","Weight_loss","Electrolytes","HT_uncompl","Metastatic_canc",
                 "Chronic_Pulmo","Cancer","Obesity","Depression","Hypothyroid",
                 "Diab_uncompl", "OSAS","Liver","Neurological", "Diab_compl", 
                 "Arrythmias" ,"Anemia_deficiency","Pulmo_Circul","Rhumato",
                 "Alcohol","Renal_fail","Peptic_ulc","Valvular","Cong_Hear_Fail",   
                 "Periph_Vasc","Anemia_bleeding","Drug","Psychoses","HIV_AIDS",
                 "Paralysis","HT_compl","Coagulopathy", "Lymphoma",
                 "elix_quartile")
```

And the number of observation:

```
> nrow(pts_raw_ps)
[1] 367169
```

I have Windows 10 64 bits; RAM 32 Gb

[image]

Not sure my computer can do parallel calculations. I have not a GPU of type CUDA

Comment: I assume your large number of variables causes the huge need for memory. Could you reduce the number of variables? Otherwise, you need to look for a HPC with more memory.

Comment: @RRDK this isn't about the number of variables; it's about the sample size.

Answer (score 1):

This is an inherent limitation of optimal matching. It requires a distance matrix, and with 367169 units, you will have a distance matrix with close to 30 billion entries in it. Each of these entries is a node in a network that is constructed by the optimal matching algorithm. This is way too big of a problem to be solved using optimal matching. There are some methods of pruning the nodes to reduce the problem size, but these methods also tend to be slow.

In addition, optimal matching will not solve the problem you are having. It tends to perform about the same as nearest-neighbor matching without replacement. Instead, you should try the many ways you can adjust nearest neighbor matching without replacement to improve balance, like adding exact matching constraints, a caliper, variable ratio matching, using a different distance measure, trying a different way of estimating the propensity score, etc. You can also look into propensity score subclassification, which can more easily accommodate having more treated than control units when estimating the ATT and is very fast to run because no pairing is done.

Essentially, you chose the worst method for your scenario, one that will not perform better than the methods you already tried and is computationally infeasible. There are many other methods available in `MatchIt` that will yield superior performance that you should try instead.